# Pivoting a union query

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, union

I currently have two large spend databases (one for 2018 another for 2019) and have been combining the results with UNION ALL, and then pivoting in Excel to get it in a format that I want (with the years as columns). This has been working fine, but I would like to do all of the work in SQL. I have gotten the PIVOT function to work for each of the separate UNION functions, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to combine the two:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-EXT-COST-3])
SELECT [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
, [Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-DESCRIPTION] AS Description


FROM [Unique CC Item Number Database]
LEFT JOIN  [Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv]
ON [Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[Accounting Unit] &'-'&[Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[Item Number] = [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
WHERE [Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].Month IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June')

GROUP BY [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
, [Jan-June_2019_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-DESCRIPTION]
PIVOT Year

UNION ALL 
TRANSFORM Sum([Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-EXT-COST-3]) 
SELECT [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
, [Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-DESCRIPTION] AS Description

FROM [Unique CC Item Number Database]
LEFT JOIN [Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv] 
ON [Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[Accounting Unit] &'-'&[Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[Item Number] = [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
WHERE [Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].Month IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June')

GROUP BY [Unique CC Item Number Database].[Cost Center-Item Number]
, [Jan-Dec_2018_Co99_SpendDB_wo_Inv].[PLI-DESCRIPTION]
PIVOT Year;
```

Each of the individual UNION queries work as expected with the pivot, but I can not figure out how to PIVOT properly with the queries combined. I have tried combining the PIVOT into one, but I keep getting an error message. The error message I get with the above code is a Syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, crosstab queries with `TRANSFORM` clause are special queries and cannot be directly integrated inside another query including `UNION` or `JOIN`. However, you can use them indirectly via saved queries. Therefore, simply save the two crosstab queries and then run them in a union query:

```
SELECT * FROM [CrossTab_2018]
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [CrossTab_2019]
```

However, to control the order and output of columns (critically needed in `UNION` queries), be sure to expand the `PIVOT` clause in crosstab query with `IN` for all available years. Doing so, even if years are not applicable (i.e., future years), an empty column will appear.

```
PIVOT Year IN (2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025)
```

Nonetheless, for readability and maintainability, always list out columns in queries and avoid the abbreviated `*` in `SELECT` clause (advised for all types of queries):

```
SELECT [Cost Center-Item Number], [Description], 
       [2015], [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020],
       [2021], [2022], [2023], [2024], [2025]
FROM [CrossTab_2018]

UNION ALL 

SELECT [Cost Center-Item Number], [Description], 
       [2015], [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020],
       [2021], [2022], [2023], [2024], [2025]
FROM [CrossTab_2019]
```

Comment: Thank you. This make sense. One issue, I have tried adding an INSERT INTO clause after the SELECT clause in my code but I am getting an error. It seems to be because of the TRANSFORM clause before the SELECT clause (since when I remove the pivot, it works fine). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but MS Access queries can only allow one SQL query at a time. Action queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) cannot be placed after `SELECT`. You can however run actions on saved `SELECT` queries.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I am new to access and am having a lot of trouble saving the Pivoted Table for either year I created with the code above. I am able to SELECT .... and then INTO a new table. But when I add TRANSFORM above the code and PIVOT at the end with the INTO clause in the same place, I get an unknown error (-3002). Is there any easier way to save a table from a query I ran?

Comment: You may need to ask a new question as I do not understand what you are attempting. Are you running a third pivot off this `UNION` query? Once again, the `TRANSFORM` crosstab query is a special query and cannot be directly run with standard methods including `INTO`. Always run operations on saved crosstab queries.

Comment: Sorry!! I understand now and it works perfectly. I did not understand that if I saved the TRANSFORM query it saves as something that I can query directly. Thank you for your help.